# Editable OutlineView with Cocoa Bindings

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray, cocoa-bindings, nstreecontroller

How do you bind the NSOutlineView (or NSTableView) so that the items can be editable?  I know that there's the editable field for it but I'm not sure how to use it so any help for it would be nice.  I have a NSTreeController that's bind to a NSArray.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editable is not a property of NSTableView or NSOutlineView but of NSTableColumn. And if you check Cocoa Bindings Reference, you'll find that NSTableColumn also exposes an NSEditableBinding (well, it doesn't *say* so, but it does -- one of the idiosyncrasies of Apple's documentation). When you set the binding, either programmatically (bind:) or in IB, add or check NSConditionallySetsEditableBindingOption to the options, and you're all set.